# Derivate of degree matrix w.r.t adjacency matrix

Tags: derivatives, graph-theory

I have a degree matrix D and I wonder what the derivate wrt its adjacency matrix
$$\frac{\partial D}{\partial A}= ?$$

I know it's a 4D-tensor, but we can vectorized the matrix so that
$$\frac{vec(D)}{vec(A)} = ?$$

where $D_{ii} = \sum_{j} A_{ij}, D_{ij} = 0, i\neq j$

I see $\frac{\partial A}{\partial A} = \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: first of all, you can consider just the vector of the diagonal entries of $D$. The rest is just the derivative of a linear function

Comment: @Exodd But that still leads to a derivative of vector wrt a matrix

Comment: as you proposed, then you can derive the vector wrt $vec(A)$